# How to sync two counters in React js using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to react js,
I want to connect two counters in React js, As if one counter value gets increased by one the other counter value should get decreased by one, And on the button click, I need to add a new set of counter pairs. Can anyone suggest to me a solution? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried to manage this?

Comment: I created two components as counter 1 and counter2 and tried to connect them using a loop, But i am not able to connect

Comment: Can you please suggest any example of how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Please share a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what it is you are wanting/trying to do. It's ok if it doesn't work, we can work with that, but what we can't, or don't, do, is debug code we can't see or write it for you. SO isn't a code writing service. If you need a hint, then may I suggest [Lifting State up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or using the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to use a "centralized state" that both components share.

Comment: Thank you Drew Rees, I will try the concepts you have suggested and implement in my code. I will post if i face any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a counter pair and have to do it multiple times, I would suggest to use `custom Hooks`.

I have created one for the purpose named `useCounter`.

Here you have to pass an `array of length 2` if initial state of counter.
And the hook will return `[couters, updateCounter, err]` the array.

You can refer to this code for insight.

Hook: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/counterHook.js

Component using hook: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/pair.js

**Note: goto https://ikqdn.csb.app/pair in `codesandbox browser`**

Comment: Hi Himanshu Singh,
I created "counter 1" and "counter 2 " as separate components, Can you suggest me a way to make these components work together,(I mean the same functionality in your code but if the two counters are separate components. )  Thank You